# [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.setState')]

Tags: axios, react-native

I get a problem with ReactNative and axios. I would like save the response URL in a state variable but I have this problem :

`[TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.setState')]`

The function :

```
githubGetUrl = () => {
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://' +  global.IP_ADDRESS + ':8080/github/link'
    }).then(function(response) {
      this.setState({githuburl: response.data.LINK})
      console.log('Résultat [' + this.state.githuburl + ']')
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error)
    });
  }
}
```

The constructor :

```
constructor (props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    clicked: '',
    githuburl: ''
  }
}
```

I already search on web but I don't find the origin of the problem...

If someone can help me, I will appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: ```setState``` is an async process, so place your ```console.log``` as a callback.

Comment: How can I do that ?

Comment: ```this.setState({githuburl: response.data.LINK}, () => console.log('Résultat [' + this.state.githuburl + ']'))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use arrow function in `then`

```
githubGetUrl = () => {
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://' +  global.IP_ADDRESS + ':8080/github/link'
    }).then((response) => {
      this.setState({githuburl: response.data.LINK})
      console.log('Résultat [' + this.state.githuburl + ']')
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error)
    });
  }
}
```